# How can you combine lines in $\LaTeX$ and lines in Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, latex

Suppose that you want to make a report about the golden section algorithm, and you want to explain the process with text in $\LaTeX$, and in every iteration you want to show in that report the values and the correct option, and then you want to continue explaining in $\LaTeX$.

For example in this code, how can you do it?

```
itmax = 10;
tolerancia = 0.2;
alfa = (-1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
ttheta[Lambda_] = Lambda^2 + 2*Lambda;
a = -3;
b = 5;
La = a + (1 - alfa)*(b - a) // N;
Mu = a + alfa*(b - a) // N;
tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
tLacalc = "*";
tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
tMucalc = "*";
Printf["With * we show you that this is an evaluate of theta(t)"]
Printf["With NO* we show you that this is an evaluate of theta(t)"]
Print["iteración_k   |   a_k    b_k   |   Lambda_k     Mu_k   |   \
theta(Lambda_k)  theta(Mu_k)"];
Do[
  L = b - a;
  Print[" In the iteration "i, " you have the values:",
      "\n a= ",a,
      "\n b= ",b,
      "\n Lamda= ",La,
      "\n Mu= ",Mu,
      "\n ",
      "\n Where the values of theeta are:",
      "\n theta (Lambda)= ",tthetaLa,
      "\n theta (Mu)=     ",tthetaMu,
   "os a =  |   ", a, "     ", b, "   |  ", La, "     ", Mu, 
   "   |  ", tthetaLa, tLacalc "      ", tthetaMu, tMucalc ];
  If[tthetaLa > tthetaMu,
   If[b - a < tolerancia, Break[]];

   a = La;
   La = Mu;
   Mu = a + alfa (b - a);
   tthetaLa = tthetaMu;
   tLacalc = " ";
   tthetaMu = ttheta[Mu];
   tMucalc = " ";,

   b = Mu;
   Mu = La;
   La = a + (1 - alfa) (b - a);
   tthetaMu = tthetaLa;
   tMucalc = " ";
   tthetaLa = ttheta[La];
   tLacalc = "*";
   ]
  , {i, 1, itmax}
  ];
solucionestimada = (Mu + La)/2;
valorestimado = ttheta[solucionestimada];
Print["La solución estimada es ", solucionestimada, 
  " donde la función toma valor ", valorestimado];
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, as far as I know there is no single package that can be used to include *Mathematica* inputs/outputs in LaTeX.

So, the best you can do is to follow 4 easy steps to include your *Mathematica* codes into LaTeX.

**STEP 1**

Save your code in PDF format using *Mathematica* itself. In this case you have to select the blue part of your code at the right side of your *Mathematica* notebook and then choose the option "Save Selection As..."

[image]

**STEP 2**
Choose a name for your (now) PDF-formatted part of code. In this example I will use the name **input.pdf**.

[image]

**STEP 3**
Insert the PDF-file into your LaTeX document with the command **\includegraphics[]{input.pdf}**:

[image]

**STEP 4**
Compile the LaTeX document and see the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Barnett's Mathscape](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb19-2/tb59barn.pdf) is what you're looking for here.

Unfortunately the link to the repository where his unix-based code was being stored appears to be dead now.