# Export matrix to $\LaTeX$ with style

Tags: matrix, export, latex

Is it possible to export a matrix to $\LaTeX$ with style?

For example this code will create a matrix with equal spacing matrix and with background colors in some cell, is it possible to export that to $\LaTeX$ ?

```
tb = Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}], {10}, {10}];
Grid[tb, Dividers -> {{{{True, False}}, {-1 -> False, 
     1 -> False}}, {{{True, False}}, {-1 -> False, 1 -> False}}}, 
 ItemSize -> {4.5, 4}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
 Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Flatten@{Table[{{2 i + 1, 2 i + 2}, {2 i + 1, 2 i + 2}} -> 
       Green, {i, 0, 4}], 
     Table[{{2 i + 1, 2 i + 2}, {2 i - 1, 2 i}} -> Pink, {i, 1, 4}], 
     Table[{{2 i - 1, 2 i}, {2 i + 1, 2 i + 2}} -> Pink, {i, 1, 4}]}}]
```

[image]

I tried to copy as $\LaTeX$ and `Export["~/1.tex",%]`, both only give the matrix content without any formattings.

Comment: A general-purpose way of getting useable $\LaTeX$ code is to `Export` as `PDF`, then import into [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and from there choose `Save As > LaTeX with PSTricks Macros`. That produces a `.tex` fragment which can go into the body of a host file as long as the latter calls `\usepackage{pstricks}` first. This isn't specific to tables, it works for anything that can be exported as `PDF`. For specific things like tables, it's also possible to generate the $\LaTeX$, but only by hand-coding it.

Comment: Please take a look at [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/how-can-you-combine-lines-in-latex-and-lines-mathematica/23539#23539).