# Override Equation structure change in mathematica - CopyToLaTeX

Tags: latex

I am writing my thesis, and when I do copy to LaTeX from Mathematica, it changes the equation variables and also it rearranges the structure of the original equation.

How can I override that ??

> *New information and further reading : http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/Mathematica/EquationEditing.html*

Its really annoying especially when I have to get the exact same form.

EXAMPLE:

## 1: Mathematica code:

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[E^(-I k( (\[Xi]/Subscript[z, 1]+u/Subscript[z, 2]) x+ (\[Eta]/Subscript[z, 1]+v/Subscript[z, 2]) y))]]
```

## 2: How it looks in Mathematica:

[image: 1]

## 3 Mathematica Output:

```
\exp \left(-i
k\left(\left(\frac{\xi
}{z_1}+\frac{u}{z_2}\right)
x+\left(\frac{\eta
}{z_1}+\frac{v}{z_2}\right)
y\right)\right)
```

## 4 Copy paste #3 into LaTeX, the result:

[image: output on PDF]
Thanks

Comment: Try `HoldForm`: `TeXForm[HoldForm[1 + x]]`

Comment: Dint work , Could you please try on your mathematica : `HoldForm[U[x, y] = 
  Subscript[E, 0]/(4 \[Pi]) E^(I k Subscript[z, 1])/Subscript[z, 1]
    E^(I k/(2 Subscript[z, 1]) ((\[Xi] - x)^2 + (\[Eta] - y)^2))]`

Comment: `HoldForm` on the equation I wanted itself gave me rearraged one: `U[x, y] = (
 Subscript[E, 0] E^(I k Subscript[z, 1]) E^((
  I k ((\[Xi] - x)^2 + (\[Eta] - y)^2))/(
  2 Subscript[z, 1])))/((4 \[Pi]) Subscript[z, 1])`

Comment: Try [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/how-can-you-combine-lines-in-latex-and-lines-mathematica/23539#23539).

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the expressions you are working with, including the transformed output.

Comment: @m_goldberg : Done. Please see edited question with example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could help?

```
SetAttributes[copyAsLatex, HoldFirst];
copyAsLatex[sth_] := CopyToClipboard[ToString[HoldForm[sth] /.
    x_ /y_ :> Divide[x, y], TeXForm]]
```

So

```
copyAsLatex[
 U[x, y] = 
  Subscript[E, 0]/(4 \[Pi]) E^(I k Subscript[z, 1])/
    Subscript[z, 
     1] E^(I k/(2 Subscript[z, 1]) ((\[Xi] - x)^2 + (\[Eta] - y)^2))]
```

copies the following to the clipboard

```
(* U(x,y)=\frac{e_0}{4 \pi } \frac{e^{i k z_1}}{z_1} e^{i \frac{k}{2 z_1} \left((\xi -x)^2+(\eta -y)^2\right)} *)
```

Comment: Can you explain why `Subscript[E,0]` gave an TeXForm of `\frac{e_0}` ?? Why the change from Caps to Small. Just curious ...

Comment: @abhilashsukumari `E` has the built in meaning of "euler's number", the base of the natural log. In standard math that's written in lowercase

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact same formatting as in the `StandardForm` output of your *Mathematica* session, then you could do the following:

```
U[x, y] = (Subscript[E, 
      0] E^(I k Subscript[z, 
         1]) E^((I k ((\[Xi] - x)^2 + (\[Eta] - y)^2))/(2 Subscript[z,
            1])))/((4 Pi) Subscript[z, 1]);

TeXForm[StandardForm[U[x, y]]]
```

> `\frac{\exp \left(\frac{i k \left((-y+\eta
>      )^2+(-x+\xi )^2\right)}{2 z_1}+i k z_1\right)
>      e_0}{4 \pi  z_1}`

Here, I added `StandardForm` because usually `TeXForm` goes via a conversion to `TraditionalForm` which re-arranges some terms, for example the `-y + η`.

This is described under ["Generalizations and Extensions"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html#365832752) in the help page for [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html).

Comment: If I understand correctly @abhilash sukumari wants the answer to include multiple \frac{}{} elements multiplied together, not everything collected into a single \frac{} as happens in this example. ie. something that has `a/b c/d` as is the form of the input`

Comment: @JonathanShock I understood it differently. The question is explicitly about `TeXForm` rearranging things. What you mention already happens in `StandardForm`. If you're right, the question is phrased incorrectly.

Comment: I don't think it's phrased incorrectly. He may be copying as LaTeX straight from his input

Comment: @Rojo Ah, that could be. I'll wait for clarification.

Comment: @Rojo : Yes, I am trying to get multiple fraction terms instead of self-arranging to compact single fraction. I shall edit the question with a simple Equation that has very different looks in standard and TeXForm.

Comment: @Rojo: Yes I was copying straight from my input, what would be the correct way to copy to LaTeX directly then ?

Comment: @abhilashsukumari I think what you are doing is just fine